# How to dynamically change the size of popup.html for Google Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The goal is to change the size of my chrome extension popup (different from a normal popup window) dynamically when the user clicks on a button.

I tried to hide the elements I have on the page by setting the hidden attribute to true. I also tried to change the window size with window.resizeTo, but nothing works.

Note: I can enlarge the window, but I can't shrink it back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just adjust the css `width` property of `<body>` element. Can also do the same with `<html>` for good measure.

```
document.body.style.width="100px";
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.width="100px";
```

Comment: It's not working. First click of the button reveals the hidden element and sets "w_height=document.body.style.height"
second click hides the element and sets     "document.body.style.height=w_height" But the window does not shrink

Comment: @Tony Height seems to be more demanding than width. Set both body and html heights at the same time. Also there should be no visible elements in the popup bigger than the popup height you set. I added example how to change html style.